# Хочу установить SQL Server 2016 на Windows 7

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-7, установка

Да я знаю что установка SQL Server 2016 Express на Windows 7 официально не поддерживается. Есть ли какой-то способ чтобы Windows 7 идентифицировалась программами как Windows 8/8.1/10? Какие файлы можно было бы подменить или может что-то установить чтобы я мог поставить SQL Server 2016 не переустанавливая ОС?
Возможно есть ещё какой-то способ обойти проверку и установить SQL Server 2016.

---

### Также попробовал такую комбинацию

1. Обновился до Windows 10
2. Установил SQL Server 2016
3. Затем откатился назад до Windows 7

Но SQL Server 2016 даже не запускался.

---

Этот же вопрос задавал на [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/q/1158695/165101).

Comment: Может быть такое ограничение введено не зря? Даже если и получится установить, то не факт, что будет корректно работать.

Comment: Имхо сомнительно, думаю это искусственное ограничение.Уверен, что ядро системы не менялось.

Comment: В чем проблема поднять виртуальную машину? Поставить не получится SQL Server 2016 на WIndows.

Comment: Виртуальную машину чтобы на ней потом работать не вариант, это тормоза, плюс тоже можно ещё предложить вариант поставить как вторую ОС Windows 8/8.1/10, но я не об этом спрашиваю.

Comment: @KonstantinTaranov Оформите ваш комментарий как ответ, я его приму.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Оформил, спасибо за обратную связь.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432026/why-can-i-not-install-sql-server-express-2016-on-windows-7-professional-64-bit-s но сам пока ещё не проверял...

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38432026/1548895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Windows 7 установить SQL Server 2016 не получится (также как и на Windows Server 2008), минимальная версия - Windows 8. Поэтому единственный доступный вариант - это виртуальная машина, при чем если попробовать [SQL Server Vnext](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-vnext-including-Linux), то можно использовать и Linux! Также скачать последние актуальные дистрибутивы по прямым ссылкам можно [здесь](http://sqlserver-kit.org/en/home/version#microsoft-sql-server-installation-files-info).

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно сделать. Минимальная доступная версия это Windows 8.
Подробнее о требованиях к оборудованию можно посмотреть [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143506.aspx#pmosr).